# pthread input thread and worker thread synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-join

I have two pthreads one of them is reading from cin and putting it in a QUEUE and the other one is a worker thread checking the QUEUE every 2 seconds and printing something if there is something in it.

This is what's in my main:

```
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Thread.h"
#include "Mutex.h"

using namespace std;

queue<string> lineup;
Mutex lock;

class InputReader:public Thread{
    private:
        string buffer;
    protected:
        virtual void run(){
            while(true){
                cout << "Please Enter some Text:\n" ;
                getline(cin,buffer);
                lock.lock();
                lineup.push(buffer);
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    public:
        InputReader(){}
        ~InputReader(){}
};


class Request: public Thread{
    protected:
        virtual void run(){
            while(true){
                sleep(2);
                lock.lock();
                if ((int)(lineup.size())>0){
                    cout << "Sending Request: " << lineup.front() << endl;
                    lineup.pop();
                }
                else{
                    cout << "Nothing to send!" <<endl;
                }
                lock.unlock();

            }
        }
    public:
        Request(){}
        ~Request(){}
};

int main(){
    Request rq;InputReader iread; 
    iread.start();  rq.start();
    iread.join(); rq.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Where Thread.h and Thread.cpp are:

```
#ifndef __THREAD_H__
#define __THREAD_H__
#include <pthread.h>

class Thread
{
    private:
        pthread_t thread;
        static void * dispatch(void *);
    protected:
        virtual void run() = 0;
    public:
        virtual ~Thread();
        void start();
        void join();
};

#endif

//  THREAD.CPP
#include "Thread.h"

Thread::~Thread(){}

void * Thread::dispatch(void * ptr)
{
    if (!ptr) return 0;
    static_cast<Thread *>(ptr)->run();
    pthread_exit(ptr);
    return 0;
}

void Thread::start(){
    pthread_create(&thread, 0, Thread::dispatch, this);
}

void Thread::join()
{
    pthread_join(thread, 0);
}
```

Mutex.h and Mutex.cpp:

```
#ifndef __MUTEX_H__
#define __MUTEX_H__
#include <pthread.h>

class Mutex
{
private:
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
public:
    Mutex();
    ~Mutex();
    void lock();
    void unlock();
    bool trylock();
};

#endif

// MUTEX.CPP -----------------------
#include "Mutex.h"
Mutex::Mutex(){
       pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, 0);
   }
   Mutex::~Mutex(){
      pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
  }
  void Mutex::lock(){
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  }
  void Mutex::unlock(){
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }
  bool Mutex::trylock()  {
      return (pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex) == 0);
  }
```

The problem is once its in the infinite loop waiting for stdin in the iread thread, the rq thread never starts. In fact, whichever .start() comes first is the one it gets stuck in... any ideas?

Comment: You are basically asking: *I have some code that does not work, can you guess without seeing it what the problem is?* You need to provide the actual code if you want anyone to be able to help.

Comment: From your description, the comment `Same as pthread_create` is a lie.

Comment: Also, the "polling every 2 second thread" suggests to me that you're probably doing it wrong. What you seem to want here is a producer/consumer algorithm. Start by reading here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

Comment: There is not enough information here to do anything. Voting to close.

Comment: I forgot I posted this. I realized posting all the classes would be too much and thought I cancelled it :/ I just editted in the details for future inquirers. Anyway problem solved. See solution below. Thank you for looking at it though

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that I needed to run **g++** with the **-lpthread** option. Does anyone know why this isn't on by default?

Comment: `-lpthread`  is not a compiler option . Its a indication that linker should use the pthread library when looking up the pthread related function API signatures.